# Euler beam equation sign confusion

Tags: conventions, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, structural-beam

Euler beam equation is defined as follows:

$$M=-EI{\frac {d^{2}w}{dx^{2}}}$$

There is a negative sign, so if the second derivative of the deflection is negative, the moment is positive. When the beam curves down, the second derivative is negative. So the moment on the beam should be positive when the beam bends down.

But normally moment is defined the other way around:

[image]

Here the moment is positive when the beam curves up. **So is there a contradiction or am I misunderstanding something?**

Comment: *Who* inserts your minus sign?  I do not think there is a standard convention here. It depends on your coordinate system. Perhaps the author's  $w$ axis points downward?

Comment: I copied the formula from Wikipedia, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory

Comment: The wiki article makes it clear that their $M(x)$ is the moment exerted on the *right* side of the beam cut at $x$ by the part to the left of $x$. Thus, when the beam bends *up* the torque exerted by the LHS is trying to bend it *down*.  Hence the sign. Other accounts may use different definitions.

Comment: @S.Rotos My mechanics of materials references do not have a negative sign on the right side of the Euler Beam Equation

Comment: @BobD Interesting, my textbook has the negative sign. It must the just that the direction of positive moment has been defined differently..

Comment: @mikestone Okay, so it seems that the sign has to do with the defined direction of positive moment?

Comment: @S.Rotos Nope. Positive bending moment is defined the same way ( a “smile”). My reference is a handbook published by the NCEE (National Council of Engineering Examiners) here in U.S.

Comment: Can you add your book reference?